# Can I create a query to store my procedure to apply on different tables with same structure in Access/SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I know in SQL, you can store procedure and save the query for further use on a same table.

For example, if you create this query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectAllCustomers @City nvarchar(30), @PostalCode nvarchar(10)
AS
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City = @City AND PostalCode = @PostalCode
GO;
```

then you can do:

```
EXEC SelectAllCustomers City = "London", PostalCode = "WA1 1DP";
```

or

```
EXEC SelectAllCustomers City = "Beijing", PostalCode = "100010";
```

Can I also save specific procedure and apply on different tables by setting table name as a parameter?

For example, it would be very helpful when managing the monthly historical report, since for each month, you have to repeat the same procedure of analyzing data.

Comment: As far as I know, no. Use VBA. Why do you have multiple tables with same structure?

Comment: As I said, every monthly report look the same, just with different data.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the table reference must be dynamic. Why do you have multiple tables with same structure instead of just 1 table?

Comment: You made a good point. Thank you and I will try to merge my tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title is somewhat confusing, since you speak of “different” tables, but all your examples work on one table (so that very confusing here).

As for supplying parameters? Yes this is common, but no requirement for some store procedure exists.

The BEST way to achieve this is to use the “built in” ability of Access to supply parameters “on the fly”. That way ahead of time you don’t have to know, or care or “plan” ahead.

So you can supply “on the fly” parameters to the report. Simply base the report on the raw table (or the query).

Then, you can supply parameters to the report using the “where” clause of the openReport.

Eg:

```
Docmd.OpenReport "rptSales",acViewPreview,,"City = 'Edmonton'"
```

So the above would open the report and restrict to the one city. Note that access is smart, and if your back end is an access back end on a network, or sql server back end, then ONLY the records that satisfy your criteria are pulled down the network pipe...

So simply use the openReport’s “where” clause. It is any valid sql “where” clause – even sub queries can be used in that were clause. No need to use store procedures, create store procedures with “known” parameters. You gain zero in performance doing that anyway – so use Access’s great built in “where” clause for this types of filtering or restricting the records based on some supplied criteria.